# При смене разрешения экрана адаптивное меню перестает показываться

Tags: jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Если развернуть меню при 992px и заново вернуть значение 1200px, то меню перестает показываться на экране. В чем ошибка?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.main-nav-trigger').click(function() {
         $(this).next('.horizontal-nav').slideToggle(700);
       }); /// отвечает за сворачивание меню
       $(window).resize(function () {
          if ($(window).width() >= 992) { 
             $(this).next('.horizontal-nav').style('display', 'block');
          } 
          else {
             $(this).next('.horizontal-nav').style('display', 'none');
          }
       }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде @YernarSadybekov написал все верно, только менять надо было не везде, а только в конструкции `$(this).next('.horizontal-nav').style(...);` => `$('.horizontal-nav').style(...);`

```
$(function() {
  var $nav = $('.horizontal-nav');

  $('.main-nav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $nav.slideToggle(700);
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $nav.css({ display: ($(this).width() >= 992 ? 'block' : 'none') });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените это:

```
$(this).next('.horizontal-nav')
```

на это:

```
$('.horizontal-nav')
```

Comment: Все сделал как вы указали, теперь даже разворачиваться не хочет меню на адаптивке. Не понимаю в чем ошибся.

Comment: а функция  **$('.main-nav-trigger').click** работает?